# Unzipping a file to a remote directory in VBA

Tags: vba, zip, unzip

I have a project where I need to extract a file from a zip, and then open that file. I had it working last week with the code:

```
 With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        .Namespace("" & UnZippedFolder).copyhere .Namespace("" & ZipFolder & _ 
                       ZipFile).Items
 End With
```

When I tried to run it this week, I got a bunch of errors as I tried to debug it.

I've moved from 'simple' (above) to 'as explicit as I can figure out' (below). I'm currently getting the error, "Object variable or With block variable not set." with the line selected that has '*' at the end. I can't figure out why this error is being thrown, or how to fix it.

```
Dim WeekNum As Integer
Dim ZipFolder As String
Dim ZipFile As String
Dim UnZippedFile As String
Dim UnZippedFolder As String
Dim objShell
Dim UZipFold
Dim ZipFoldAndFile
If Proceed = False Then Exit Sub

WeekNum = Workbooks("personal.xlsb").Sheets("Dates").Range("WeekNum").Value
ZipFolder = "\\server\path\" ' obfuscated because I must, sorry
ZipFile = "Prefix" & "Week" & WeekNum & " (xlsx 07 format).zip" ' change the 11 to the last 2 digits of the year! 
UnZippedFolder = "\\server\path\" ' obfuscated, again, because I must
UnZippedFile = "Logging_11" & "Week" & WeekNum & " (xlsx 07 format).xlsx"

Set objShell = New Shell
UZipFold = objShell.Namespace("" & UnZippedFolder)
ZipFoldAndFile = objShell.Namespace("" & ZipFolder & ZipFile)

UZipFold.copyhere (objShell.Namespace("" & ZipFolder & ZipFile).Items) '*'
```

Comment: Try changing all your declarations of "as String" to "as Variant". I seem to remember having this exact same problem and it was because of the variable types passed to Shell being strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare your paths or anything passed to the shell object as variants, not strings.

See here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/windowsxpunzip.htm